# Button does not respond to onClick event

Tags: android, button, onclick, onclicklistener, buttonclick

Hi everyone I ve been searching this a lot but I couldn't find an answer that would work in my case. In my layout i have a listview and outside the list and more specific above i have an imageview an editText which work as a search and a custom Button!The problem is that when i press the button does not start the Activity which i have put in th Intent.Why is this happening?I cannot find the error and so far i had never problem with button events.
Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="LIST OF PATIENTS"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#33B5E5" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/search_user" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonadd"
    android:onClick="button_click"
    android:src="@drawable/add" />
</LinearLayout>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linear"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Search patient" />
```

the button is the right on the top next to autocomplete.In the .java doc i have right this code as far as concerned the button:
In the onCreate

```
addp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
addp.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In th onClick

```
case R.id.add:
    Intent add= new Intent(sqlviewpatients.this,afprognosis.class);             
    startActivity(add);
    break;
```

I ve been doing the same thing to others button and they working only this one does not respond to onClick events.Please tell me what I am doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Comment: In your xml code I can only find one button with the id addpatient? So you should use addp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addpatient);

Comment: sorry I editted it's add and my xml!but again nothing!why is this happening?

Comment: have u tried to Log something inside the `case R.id.add:` ?

Comment: yes and it doesn't print it!and is happening only to this specific button!The buttons which i have in my custom action bar works for example!Is it possible the custom action bar affect this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks everyone for your answers and your time!I appreciate it

Second i found where the error was. the onClick method should have an @overide above

Comment: The `@Override` annotation does nothing other than help make code cleaner. It doesn't actually tell the compiler, here make sure you override this method.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ids do not match:

```
addp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
```

and:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/addpatient"
```

Change the java to:

```
addp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addpatient);
```

**EDIT:** If you are defining your onClick within the XML then you should not need to set an onClickListener within the java code. Just make the code:

```
Intent add= new Intent(sqlviewpatients.this,afprognosis.class);             
startActivity(add);
```

within a method that is called `button_click`.

Comment: I edit  it was my mistake!the program runs but only the onClick in this specific button does not work

Comment: @user2358336 updated answer. If this doesn't help, could you post the entire method that contains the case R.id.add in it?

Comment: I had remove the  button_click to the xml before i post the question but no luck again :/ !i add and the .java doc

Comment: customwindow3 is my custom actionbar which extends Activity and it has 2 buttons the logout and the header!The program runs the only thing is that button  which doesn t respond to the onClick method and does not start the intent

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT after Code update**

Okay, after reading the code you just posted: `sqlviewpatients`:

- what does `customwindow3` look like? Does it inherit from `ListActivity` or what?
- This class only implements `onClickListener` and so a bunch of code won't get executed, including `onCreate` unless of course, `customwindow3` does

**Original**

1) your button's id is `addpatient` not `add` which is the clause if you switch statement

2) have you looked into doing this:

```
 public void button_click(View v)
 {
   Intent .....
 }
```

Also, from the snippet you posted this:

```
addp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
addp.setOnClickListener(this);
```

shouldn't actually run (you'll get a null pointer exception) since there is no element with that id (unless of course you've defined that somewhere else and didn't show us).

Comment: My mistake is add in the xml too i just edited!also the public void button_click(View v)method ise different from the onClick which I use?

Comment: Use use public void button_click(View v). It's a bit easier to manage and simpler too.

Comment: Oh and do us all a favour, update your profile with real name,etc.

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverflow :/ i will change it

Comment: No worries! Welcome. I hope you get a lot of this site :)